# Apache Flink: The RemoteEnvironment cannot be instantiated when running in a pre-defined context

Tags: apache-flink

Does any one know, what is the root of the following error while running a program on a remote Flink cluster?

How can I resolve it?

```
 org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:512)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.runBlocking(Client.java:252)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgramBlocking(CliFrontend.java:675)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:326)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:977)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1027)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The RemoteEnvironment cannot be instantiated when running in a pre-defined context (such as Command Line Client, Scala Shell, or TestEnvironment)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.RemoteEnvironment.<init>(RemoteEnvironment.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.RemoteEnvironment.<init>(RemoteEnvironment.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(ExecutionEnvironment.java:1155)
    at org.apache.flink.test.myProj.main(myProj.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:497)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Flink program, you need to use

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
```

to retrieve the `ExecutionEnvironment`. This automatically fetches either a local environment (when you execute from your IDE) or a cluster environment (when you use the command-line client).

You would only use the `RemoteEnvironment`, if you wanted to submit a Flink program to a remote cluster.

Comment: I just used the following command and submitted the program to the remote cluster.                                                                               ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment("Jobemanger", port,parallelism);                                                                                 Anyway I did what you already said but, still the same error exists.

Comment: Please change it to ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment() and rebuild your program. It will then execute correctly.

Answer (score 0):

to submit you job to remote environment (where your code using .createRemoteEnvironment) you can only do it through API call instead from CLI